# ng-model does not accept the value entered through the jquery time picker ;

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, jquery-plugins

I created a time-type input box, whose value is supposed to enter the variable in the scope ( with ng-model),The time selection is by a drop-down with hours,it created by the jquery time picker plugin. but when  I chose a hour,I can see the selected value in the Input box , but the input has 'ng-invalid' class,---> Value did not enter the model.

the jquery time picker script& link:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/timepicker/1.3.5/jquery.timepicker.min.css">
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/timepicker/1.3.5/jquery.timepicker.min.js"></script>
```

the jquery plugin(placed in directive):

```
app.directive("timepicker", ["$timeout", function ($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: "C",
        transclude: true,
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {
            $timeout(function () {

                element.timepicker({
                    timeFormat: 'HH:mm',
                    interval: 15,
                    minTime: '24',
                    maxTime: '23:00',
                    startTime: '00:00',
                    dynamic: false,
                    dropdown: true,
                    scrollbar: true          
                });
                angular.element(".ui-timepicker-viewport").addClass('scrollbar');
                angular.element(".ui-timepicker-viewport").addClass('scrollbar-primary2');

            });
        }
    }
}]);
```

the input:

```
@Html.TextBox("rt-time", null, new
                       {
                           id = "rt-time",
                           @class = Model.Rtl ? "input-field time-input timepicker rtl-position" : "input-field time-input clockpicker ltr-position",
                           ng_model = "newOrder.routes[0].time",
                           required = "required",
                           aria_label = @UBUS.Resources.Languages.HomePage.HomePage.PlaceholderTime,
                           placeholder = @UBUS.Resources.Languages.HomePage.HomePage.PlaceholderTime,
                           autocomplete = "off"
                       })
```

the dropdown created by jquery timepicker plugin:
[image]

the input got 'ng-invalid' class after i selected time
[image]

Comment: Have you tried watching your input filed ng-model?

Comment: yes, its get nothing

Comment: try running angular digest cycle again, There is a possibility that your ng model is not in angular Js life cycle.

Comment: Consider using a third-party library like [Angular-UI Timepicker](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!timepicker)

Comment: i cant, this is what my boss want